# segmentation fault in Ruby RDF/Sparql client with CONSTRUCT query

Tags: ruby, sparql, virtuoso

I want to retrieve a TTL from a [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) endpoint.

```
query(construct_query).each_statement do |statement|
  puts statement.inspect
end
```

The `CONSTRUCT` query returns **~652977** statements.

```
CONSTRUCT {
  ?s ?p ?o
}
FROM <http://tempgraph>
WHERE {
  ?s ?p ?o .
}
```

But I get a segmentation fault.

```
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rdf-raptor-1.99.0/lib/rdf/raptor/ffi/v2/parser.rb:209: [BUG] Segmentation fault at     0x00000000000000
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0057 p:---- s:0289 e:000288 CFUNC  :raptor_parser_parse_chunk
c:0056 p:0018 s:0282 E:001128 METHOD /usr/local/bundle/gems/rdf-raptor-1.99.0/lib/rdf/raptor/ffi/v2/parser.rb:209
c:0055 p:0025 s:0278 E:001198 RESCUE /usr/local/bundle/gems/rdf-raptor-1.99.0/lib/rdf/raptor/ffi/v2/parser.rb:163
c:0054 p:0056 s:0275 E:001be0 METHOD /usr/local/bundle/gems/rdf-raptor-1.99.0/lib/rdf/raptor/ffi/v2/parser.rb:157
c:0053 p:0175 s:0268 E:0006d8 METHOD /usr/local/bundle/gems/rdf-raptor-1.99.0/lib/rdf/raptor/ffi/v2/parser.rb:92
c:0052 p:0018 s:0262 E:000110 METHOD /usr/local/bundle/gems/rdf-raptor-1.99.0/lib/rdf/raptor/ffi.rb:118
c:0051 p:0048 s:0257 E:001290 METHOD /usr/local/bundle/gems/rdf-raptor-1.99.0/lib/rdf/raptor/ffi.rb:84
c:0050 p:0130 s:0252 E:000f38 METHOD /app/lib/queries.rb:146
... etc
```

However testing to query the Virtuoso endpoint via HTTP directly, the result is successfully fetched and created.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'linkeddata'
require 'cgi'

query = "CONSTRUCT { ?s ?p ?o  } FROM <http://tempgraph> WHERE { ?s ?p ?o . }"
baseURL = "http://localhost:8890/sparql/"
sparqlURL=baseURL+"?query=#{CGI.escape query}"
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(sparqlURL))


File.open("response.ttl", "wb") do |res|
  res.puts response.body
end
```

And it creates the full TTL

```
$ cat response.ttl | wc -l
652996
```

[EDIT]
The **response.ttl** fetched from the endpoint via HTTP can be successfully serialized into RDF via the RDF/Ruby library. Hence, it is safe to assume that it is the SPARQL client.

```
  RDF::Writer.open("/app/output.rdf") do |writer|
    RDF::Reader.open("/app/response.ttl") do |reader|
      reader.each_statement do |statement|
        writer << statement
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: The description doesn't seem to implicate Virtuoso, so I wonder about that tag.  The question seems like a strong candidate for the [rdf-raptor mailing list](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-rdf-ruby/), as it looks bug-like to me, with the local file parsing possibly being handled differently than the download stream parsing...

Comment: You are right. It is due to some bug in the parsing of the result after calling the construct. I worked around it by calling directly the endpoints and not parsing the result afterwards, just returning it as is.